# xaxis label text words overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can i make the label text in the fiddle to be displayed the same way when exporting to image or pdf?

`fiddle`http://jsfiddle.net/hy5gx3v9/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `exporting: allowHTML: true` if you would like to use HTML elements during exporting the chart.

```
exporting: {
  allowHTML: true
}
```

The set the `xAxis.labels.style.textOverflow` equal to `none`.
After setting mentioned things, additionally you can delete the `style` attribute within returned string of the `xAxis.labels.formatter`:

```
labels: {
  align: 'right',
  useHTML: true,
  formatter: function() { //use formatter                                   
    return '<span class="qTitle">' + this.value + '</span>';
  },
  style: {
    textOverflow: 'none',
  }
},
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/song62xr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.allowHTML

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't, however, the best way to do it would be making images and a pdf yourself, and then making buttons for it. 
By the way, when I removed all the gibberish, it exported just fine.

Comment: what do you mean by making images by yourself??? And those gibberish text is just a placeholder for long label text...

Comment: I mean creating images using snipping tool or so, to have that get downloaded, and you could make footnotes to shorten the label